# loop throught array of objects then filter and also create new object within

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops, object

I have an array of objects like this below. As you can see, i have `rows` nested inside `input` and `rows` is also array of objects.

```
let input = [
    {
        "title": "ENGINEERING",
        "rows": [
            { "risk": "P1", "radarLink": "rdar://92642113" },
            { "risk": "P2", "radarLink": "rdar://92694095" },
            { "risk": "P3", "radarLink": "rdar://92694235" },
        ],
    },
    {
        "title": "ENVIRONMENT",
        "rows": [
            { "risk": "P1", "radarLink": "rdar://92684289" },
            { "risk": "P2", "radarLink": "rdar://92695531" },
            { "risk": "P5", "radarLink": "rdar://92424550" },
        ],
    },
]
```

First of all, i want to filter `rows` and only get those objects whose `risk` === 'P1'. Then i also want to create a new object named `p2PlusRow` which will hold the count of objects whose value of `risk` !== 'P1. This new object `p2PlusRow` will gave `count`as mentioned above. It also has a property named `radarLink`. This is nothing but concatenation of radarLink whose risk !== 'P1'
For e.g. in `ENGINEERING`, there are 2 objects whose risk is not equal to P1. the radar links of those are `rdar://92694095` and `rdar://92694235`. So the concatenated value would be rdar://92694095&92694235 (each radar ticket is appended as shown below

```
let output = [
    {
        "title": "ENGINEERING",
        "rows": [
            { "risk": "P1", "radarLink": "rdar://92642113" },
        ],
        "p2PlusRow": {
            "count": "2",
            "radarLink": "rdar://92694095&92694235"
        }
    },
    {
        "title": "ENVIRONMENT",
        "rows": [
            { "risk": "P1", "radarLink": "rdar://92684289" },
        ],
        "p2PlusRow": {
            "count": "2",
            "radarLink": "rdar://92695531&92424550"
        }
    },
]
```

In order to achieve this result, i tried a few things but i am stuck on getting the `count` and `radarLink` values dynamically. Below is the tried code

```
let output = input?.map((obj) => ({
   ...obj,
   rows: obj.rows.filter((row) => row.risk === 'P1',
   p2PlusRow: { count: 2, radarLink: 'link' } 
}));
```

As you can see p2PlusRow is static values as i have not figured out how to loop through rows and get count and radarLink values. can someone let me know how to proceed in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that will mutate the input array. If you are ok with that, you can use this

```
for (const title of input) {
    let count = 0;
    let rdars = [];
    title.rows = title.rows.filter((row) => {
        if (row.risk === 'P1') {
            return true;
        } else {
            count++;
            rdars.push(row.radarLink.replace('rdar://', ''));
            return false;
        }
    });
    title['p2PlusRow'] = {};
    title.p2PlusRow['count'] = count;
    title.p2PlusRow['radarLink'] = 'rdar://' + rdars.join('&');
}
```

Working snippet in case you want to see it run:

```js
let input = [
    {
        title: 'ENGINEERING',
        rows: [
            { risk: 'P1', radarLink: 'rdar://92642113' },
            { risk: 'P2', radarLink: 'rdar://92694095' },
            { risk: 'P3', radarLink: 'rdar://92694235' },
        ],
    },
    {
        title: 'ENVIRONMENT',
        rows: [
            { risk: 'P1', radarLink: 'rdar://92684289' },
            { risk: 'P2', radarLink: 'rdar://92695531' },
            { risk: 'P5', radarLink: 'rdar://92424550' },
        ],
    },
];

for (const title of input) {
    let count = 0;
    let rdars = [];
    title.rows = title.rows.filter((row) => {
        if (row.risk === 'P1') {
            return true;
        } else {
            count++;
            rdars.push(row.radarLink.replace('rdar://', ''));
            return false;
        }
    });
    title['p2PlusRow'] = {};
    title.p2PlusRow['count'] = count;
    title.p2PlusRow['radarLink'] = 'rdar://' + rdars.join('&');
}

console.log(input);
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

You can use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to do what you want.

```js
let input = [{
    "title": "ENGINEERING",
    "rows": [{
        "risk": "P1",
        "radarLink": "rdar://92642113"
      },
      {
        "risk": "P2",
        "radarLink": "rdar://92694095"
      },
      {
        "risk": "P3",
        "radarLink": "rdar://92694235"
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    "title": "ENVIRONMENT",
    "rows": [{
        "risk": "P1",
        "radarLink": "rdar://92684289"
      },
      {
        "risk": "P2",
        "radarLink": "rdar://92695531"
      },
      {
        "risk": "P5",
        "radarLink": "rdar://92424550"
      },
    ],
  },
]

const output = input.map(department => {
  const rest = department.rows.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    if (cur.risk === "P1") acc.rows.push(cur);
    else {
      const id = cur.radarLink.split("//")[1];
      acc.p2PlusRow.count++;
      acc.p2PlusRow.radarLink.push(id);
    }
    return acc;
  }, {
    rows: [],
    p2PlusRow: {
      count: 0,
      radarLink: []
    }
  });
  rest.p2PlusRow.radarLink = `rdar://${rest.p2PlusRow.radarLink.join("&")}`
  return {
    title: department.title,
    ...rest
  };
});

console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

#### Explanation

This looks much more complicated than it actually is.

Primarily you want to `map()` as you want a result for each and every item in your array.

Then you need to `reduce()` the `rows`. What we do here is essentially creating a new object in the form you would like to have it. To do so we declare the following as a start value for our new object:

```js
{
    rows: [],
    p2PlusRow: {
      count: 0,
      radarLink: [],
    }
}
```

Now using that start value, essentially you loop over all the rows and for each row you check if `risk === "P1"`. If it is you just add it to the `rows` field. If it is not, we increase the `counter` and push the `id` within the `radarLink` onto an the `radarLink` array.

The result of the `reduce()` therefore has the filtered `rows`, the `count` value and an array of `ids` for the radar link. Now we only have to concatenate the resulting link using those `ids` and we can return a new object which holds the result of the reduce operation and the `title` as this remains untouched.

#### Remarks

Just two remarks on my solution:

- You would not need to actually `count` as the array `radarLink` *does the counting for you*. So instead of counting within `reduce()` we could just set `count` to `radarLink.length` after the reduction which is arguably a minor improvement on the above. Because the difference is certainly (almost) irrelevant and I think it is easier to understand I won't update my solution.
- To make this solution completely [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) you just need to create a copy of the `risk` obect when you `push()` it onto the `rows` array like this  `acc.rows.push({ ...cur })`. Everything else already works on copies, therefore your input remains untouched.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a helper function, called `partition`, that behaves in a similar way to `.filter()`, however, it allows you to keep the elements you return `false` for. In the below implementation of that function, the elements you return `false` for are in the first index (`0`) of the returned array, and the elements that you return `true` for are in the second index (index `1`) of the returned array `partion()` gives you. You can then use the elements array are not P1 to get the count by taking it's `.length`. You can also use this array to get the `radarLink` values by mapping each non P1 row to its `radarLink` without the leading `rdar://` using `.replace()`, and then using `.join('&')` to concatenate all of them together:

```js
const input = [ { "title": "ENGINEERING", "rows": [ { "risk": "P1", "radarLink": "rdar://92642113" }, { "risk": "P2", "radarLink": "rdar://92694095" }, { "risk": "P3", "radarLink": "rdar://92694235" }, ], }, { "title": "ENVIRONMENT", "rows": [ { "risk": "P1", "radarLink": "rdar://92684289" }, { "risk": "P2", "radarLink": "rdar://92695531" }, { "risk": "P5", "radarLink": "rdar://92424550" }, ], }, ];

const patition = (arr, pred) => {
  const res = [[], []];
  for(const elem of arr) {
    const idx = +pred(elem); // falsy = 0, truthy = 1
    res[idx].push(elem);
  }
  return res;
}

let output = input.map((obj) => {
  const [nonP1Rows, p1Rows] = patition(obj.rows, row => row.risk === "P1");
  const concatRadarLinks = nonP1Rows.map(row => row.radarLink.replace('rdar://', '')).join('&');
  return {
    title: obj.title,
    rows: p1Rows,
    p2PlusRow: {count: nonP1Rows.length, radarLink: `rdar://${concatRadarLinks}`}
  }
});

console.log(output);
```